# Umbraco via Nuget - how do I change the database?

Tags: nuget, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed Umbraco 7 via Nuget

Empty ASP.NET 4.5 project
Package Manager console command: install-package umbracocms
Build & run, following the Umbraco wizard

Looking in the web.config this is writing to the SQL Server CE database on my system which I definitely DO NOT WANT because of a known issue with Web Matrix / IIS Express and SQL CE

[Link to known issue on Umbraco forums](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621)

How do I tell Umbraco to use my SQL Server 2012 Express database? Is it just the web.config that I change? Do I do this before building & running for the first time?

Comment: If you just had installed Umbraco with nuget you have to build it and then run it. Then for the first time you will have the chance to select the type of database you want.

Comment: Yeah it was hidden away on the custom install. I was expecting it to prompt me along the default path as it does if installing via WebMatrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the project and run in (without debugging).

When you are asked to enter a username, email address and password do so.

Before hitting the green INSTALL button, click 'Custom'.

The custom install screen allows you to choose which database to install to. In my case I have two versions of SQL Server (2008 R2 and 2012 Express and the former I don't have admin rights to) but there is only one SQL Server option. I had to specify a custom connection string like so:

```
Data Source=APIWSEMMA\MYSQL2012;Initial Catalog=MyUmbraco;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword
```

Now begin the installation. You should see all the tables created in your database when it is finished.